# Sidekiq worker's responsibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I would like to know if it is a best design practice to put many database interactions in Sidekiq.

I have a service object that delivers SMS messages to `User`. It just retrieves `id` of users and calls `.perform_async` on a Sidekiq worker class.

The SMS contains many information about other models. Therefore the worker has a long `#perform` method that just sets a number of interim variables.

For instance, it is querying tables such as `jobs`, `bids`, `business`, and calling associations on ActiveRecord objects.

Should it be the service's responsibility to retreive all the data, and simply pass those `id`s to the worker? Or can I just pass in `id`s of `user` and let the worker worry about database and associations?

Comment: I think putting the code that retrieves the data to the worker would be more efficient since it would reduce the response time because these are made in the background and you could also create a special query class or something for those if you wanna incapsulate it and then use that class in the worker's code. Plus it's not a good idea to pass objects as parameters to the worker, so you'd have to pase the ids of all those objects and retrieve them again anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, putting a lot of database work in your worker is totally normal, just remember to stick to Sidekiq's Best Practices.

1. Make your job parameters small and simple.
2. Make your job idempotent and transactional.
3. Embrace concurrency.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices